On convergence of (non-orthogonal) projections in Hilbert space
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\mathcal{H}_n$ be a sequence of finite dimensional subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$ whose dimensions monotonically increase to $\infty$. The subspaces $\mathcal{H}_n$ are not assumed to be nested. Write $P_n$ for the orthogonal projection onto  $\mathcal{H}_n$.
Now let $E_n$ be a fixed sequence of bounded idempotent operators on $\mathcal{H}$ such that the image of $E_n$ is $\mathcal{H}_n$ and $E_n$ acts as identity on $\mathcal{H}_n$, that is, $E_n$ is a not necessarily orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{H}_n$. Consider the following three statements:
(1) $P_n$ converges strongly to 1 (the identity operator on $\mathcal{H}$)
(2) $E_n$ converges strongly to 1
(3) the adjoints of $E_n$ converge strongly to 1.
My question is: How are these statements related? Does any of the three imply any of the others? Perhaps all three are equivalent? Proofs or counterexamples or just book references regarding any of the implications will be appreciated.
EDIT: I'm interested in the above question particularly in the case when the operators $E_n$ are assumed in addition to be uniformly bounded.

Just to confirm, what does strong convergence mean here? This question suggests that the meaning of the term is not entirely universal.

@TheoBendit: in the context of this question, "strongly" clearly means "in the strong operator topology" (that is, pointwise convergence).  A sequence of projections as described in the question can never converge in norm.

@TheoBendit Indeed, by "strongly" I mean "in the strong operator topology".

You should assume that $|E_n|$ are uniformly bounded. Otherwise $2$ and $3$ are not satisfied, while $1$ may hołd.

@RyszardSzwarc : That's not obvious to me but indeed I'm interested in the case when $E_n$ are uniformly bounded. I will edit and add that in the question.

In the conditions described, including the requirement of being uniformly bounded,
$\def\h{\mathcal H}$

1 ) does imply 2): Let $A_n=E_n-P_n$. Then $E_n=P_n+A_n$, with $A_n=A_n(1-P_n)$ (since $A_nP_n=0$). The uniform boundedness condition guarantees that there exists $c>0$ with $\|A_n\|\leq c$ for all $n$. Now
$$
\|A_nx\|=\|A_n(1-P_n)x\|\leq c\|(1-P_n)x\|\to0. 
$$
That is, $A_n\to0$ sot; and then $E_n=P_n+A_n\to1$.

2 ) does imply 1) For $P_nx$ minimizes the distance from $x$ to $\h_n$. This means that for all $x\in\h$,
$$
\|x-E_nx\|\geq\|x-P_nx \|.
$$
So if $E_nx\to x$, then $P_nx\to x$. That is, if $E_n\to1$ strongly then  $P_n\to1$ strongly.

2 ) does not imply 3): Fix an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$  and $\{E_{kj}\}$ the corresponding matrix units. Put $\mathcal H_n=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, and let $E_n=P_n+E_{1,n+1}$. Then $E_n\to1$ strongly, for
$$
E_n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ke_k\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^nc_ke_k+c_{n+1}e_1\to\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ke_k.
$$
But
$$
E_n^*\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ke_k\Big)=\sum_{k=1}^nc_ke_k+c_{1}e_{n+1}
$$
does not converge if $c_1\ne0$.



When uniform boundedness is not assumed, 1) does not imply 2), even when the subspaces are nested. For instance let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis and $\mathcal H_n=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Let $E_n=P_n+A_n$, where
$$
A_n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_ke_k\Big)=n\,\sum_{k=1}^n c_{n+k}e_k. 
$$
We have $P_nA_n(1-P_n)=A_n$, so $E_n=P_n+A_n$ is an idempotent onto $\mathcal H_n$. But $\{E_n\}$ does not converge sot. Indeed, this follows from the fact that $\{A_n\}$ does not converge sot (since $\{P_n\}$ does). We have
$$
\Big\|A_n\Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k\,e_k\Big)\Big\|^2
=\Big\|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n+k}\,e_k\Big\|^2
=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n^2}{(n+k)^2}
\geq\frac{n^3}{4n^2}=\frac n4,
$$
showing that $\{A_nx\}$ may fail to converge.

Nice (+). $2),$ implies $1)$ as well.

Very nice counterexamples indeed. Thank you, that seems to settle it.

The ranges of $E_n^*$ and $P_n$ do not need to coincide. So your argument $3\implies 1$ does not work

Good catch. I'll edit.

I'm afraid I didn't have time to check the details in your answer until now. I checked it now and it seems that in your first counterexample (1) does not imply (2), the range of $E_n$ is not contained in $\mathcal{H}_n$. Also, in the second counterexample, (2) does not imply (3), the operators $E_n$ don't seem to be idempotent. Perhaps these can be fixed, but it's not obvious to me how.

The first ones, I need to check if the example can be saved; my bad. The second ones, they are idempotents;  in fact, they are the adjoints of the first ones.

Yes, they are indeed idempotents. Sorry, my bad.

Please take a look at the edit.

Excellent, thanks for the changes. I wonder, could there be some natural additional assumption under which (2) implies (3)?

Other than "selfadjoint", I'd be surprised (but then I know how often I get things wrong...) As my example shows, taking adjoint is not strongly continuous, so you are looking for a condition that forces said continuity on a subset. Right now I cannot imagine what it could be.

for (2) to imply (3) Isn't it enough that the orthogonal projections onto the kernels of $E_n$ tend to 0?  But then such a condition may not be that useful...

Yes, but it doesn't look like a very testable condition to me.

I asked somewhat related question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957638/on-the-preimages-under-injective-operators-of-a-sequence-of-subspaces-of-a-hilbe

$3)$ does not imply $1).$ For this purpose we consider the example provided by @Martin Argerami. Let $$E_n=Q_n+E_{n+1,1}$$ where $Q_n$ denotes the orthogonal projection on the linear span of $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^n$ and $E_{k,l}x=\langle x,e_l\rangle e_k.$ Then $E_n^*=Q_n+E_{1,n+1}.$ We have $E_n^*\to I$ strongly as $Q_n\to I$ and $E_{1,n+1}\to 0.$ The range $\mathcal{H}_n={\rm Im}\,E_n$  is equal to the linear span of $e_1+e_{n+1}$ and $\{e_k\}_{k=2}^n.$ Thus $P_n(e_1+e_{n+1})=e_1+e_{n+1}$ and $P_n(e_1-e_{n+1})=0$ as $e_1-e_{n+1}$ is orthogonal to the range of $E_n.$ Hence $P_ne_1={1\over 2}(e_1+e_{n+1}).$ We obtain $P_ne_1\not\to e_1.$

I'm afraid I didn't have time to check the details in these answers until now. I already posted a comment to the other answer, that applies to yours as well: The range of the operators $E_n$ is not contained in $\mathcal{H}_n$.

There is no $\mathcal{H}_n$ in my answer. But if you insist on using that symbol define $\mathcal{H}_n={\rm Im},E_n.$

Yes, but there is $\mathcal{H}_n$ in my question:). So if you take $\mathcal{H}_n$ to be the image of $E_n$, are the operators $P_n$ in your answer orthogonal projections onto  $\mathcal{H}_n$?

Yes, by definition they are. I have used the notation in your OP. The range of $E_n$ is denoted by $\mathcal{H}_n$ and $P_n$ are orthogonal projections onto $\mathcal{H}_n.$

I see, thanks for the clarification.
