On the preimages under injective operators of a sequence of subspaces of a Hilbert space tending to 0
Let $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ be two separable Hilbert spaces and let $A_n:\mathcal{H}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{H}_2$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded injective linear operators with a common range $\mathcal{R}$ which is dense in $
\mathcal{H}_2$.
Let $\mathcal{K}_n$ be a sequence of closed subspaces of $\mathcal{H}_2$ such that the orthogonal projections onto $\mathcal{K}_n$ tend strongly to 0 as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Assume that $\mathcal{R}\cap \mathcal{K}_n$ is dense in $\mathcal{K}_n$ for all $n$ and let $\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n$ be the pre-image of $\mathcal{K}_n$ under  $A_n$.
My question is: in this situation, is it true that the orthogonal projections onto $\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n$ tend strongly to 0? If not, is there some natural additional condition (other than  $A_n$ being bijective) under which this is true?
EDIT: Some natural (for me) additional conditions are: Assume that $\mathcal{H}_2 = \mathcal{H}_1$, $A_n$ tends strongly to the identity operator, $A_n$ are selfadjoint, and $\mathcal{K}_n$ is a decreasing sequence of subspaces.

This is not even true when $A_n$ are unitaries. For example, let $\mathcal{H}_1 = \mathcal{H}_2 = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $S$ be the rightward bilateral shift and $A_n = S^n$. Let $\mathcal{K}_n = \overline{\text{span}}\{e_k\}_{k \geq n}$. Then as $\mathcal{K}_n \searrow \{0\}$, we have the orthogonal projections onto $\mathcal{K}_n$ converge strongly to $0$. But $\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n = \overline{\text{span}}\{e_k\}_{k \geq 0}$ for all $n$, so the orthogonal projections onto $\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n$ certainly do not tend to $0$.

Given some additional assumptions, we have the following result:
Proposition: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $A_n$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of operators on $\mathcal{H}$ which converges in strong$^\ast$ topology to $1$ (i.e., both $A_n$ and $A_n^\ast$ converge strongly to $1$), $\mathcal{K}_n \subset \mathcal{H}$ be a sequence of closed subspaces s.t. $P_{\mathcal{K}_n} \to 0$ strongly (where $P_{\mathcal{K}_n}$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{K}_n$), and $\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n = A_n^{-1}(\mathcal{K}_n)$. Then $P_{\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n} \to 0$ strongly.
Lemma: If $B_n$ is a sequence of uniformly bounded sequence of operators converging strong$^\ast$ to $1$, and $B_n = U_n|B_n|$ is the polar decomposition of $B_n$, then $U_n \to 1$ strong$^\ast$.
Proof: Since $B_n$ is uniformly bounded and $B_n \to 1$ strong$^\ast$, we have $|B_n|^2 = B_n^\ast B_n \to 1$ strongly. Taking square roots is strongly continuous on uniformly bounded sets, so $|B_n| \to 1$. Now, fix $\xi \in H$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then for large $n$, $\|B_n\xi - \xi\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\||B_n|\xi - \xi\| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, so, as $U_n|B_n|\xi = B_n\xi$,
$$\|U_n\xi - \xi\| \leq \|U_n\|\|\xi - |B_n|\xi\| + \|B_n\xi - \xi\| < \epsilon$$
Thus, $U_n \to 1$ strongly. Using $U_n^\ast B_n\xi = |B_n|\xi$, we similarly have $U_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly. $\square$
Now, consider $B_n = [(1 - P_{\mathcal{K}_n})A_n]^\ast$. Note that,
$$\ker(B_n^\ast) = \ker((1 - P_{\mathcal{K}_n})A_n) = A_n^{-1}(\mathcal{K}_n) = \widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n$$
So $\overline{\text{range}}(B_n) = \ker(B_n^\ast)^\perp = \widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n^\perp$. Let the polar decomposition of $B_n$ be $B_n = U_n|B_n|$. Then $U_nU_n^\ast = P_{\overline{\text{range}}(B_n)} = 1 - P_{\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n}$. Note that $B_n = A_n^\ast(1 - P_{\mathcal{K}_n}) \to 1$ strongly as $A_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly, $P_{\mathcal{K}_n} \to 0$ strongly, and $A_n$ is uniformly bounded. Moreover, $B_n^\ast = (1 - P_{\mathcal{K}_n})A_n \to 1$ as well as $A_n \to 1$ strongly, $P_{\mathcal{K}_n} \to 0$ strongly, and $A_n$ is uniformly bounded. Finally, $\|B_n\| \leq \|A_n\|$, so $B_n$ is uniformly bounded. Thus, by the lemma above $U_n \to 1$ and $U_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly. Hence, $1 - P_{\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n} = U_nU_n^\ast \to 1$ strongly, i.e., $P_{\widetilde{\mathcal{K}}_n} \to 0$ strongly.
Remark: $A_n \to 1$ strongly already implies, via uniform boundedness principle, that $A_n$ is uniformly bounded, so that assumption is actually redundant.

Thank you for the nice example. But  what if we take $\mathcal{H}_1=\mathcal{H}_2$ and assume in addition that $A_n$ converges strongly to the identity operator?

@S.Z. That seems quite specific. I’ll have to think about this more, but my gut instinct is that it should be true in that case.

In the example I have in mind $A_n$ is a sequence of mollifiers acting from an $L^2$-space to a Sobolev space, so this condition does hold. Somehow I simply forgot to mention it initially however.

@S.Z. For the sake of clarifying some possible additional assumptions you might also want to add, is it true that $A_n^\ast$ also strongly converges to $1$? Also, is it true that $\mathcal{K}_n$ is a decreasing sequence of subspaces?

Yes, one can assume that, and even that $A_n$ are selfadjoint. I edited the question.

@S.Z. I’ll think more under these additional assumptions then.

@S.Z. I’ve edited my answer to add in a proof showing that in your specific case, the result is true.

Thanks, this helps a lot. I need something a bit more general with the operators acting between two different Hilbert spaces but I think I will be able to figure this out.
